# Display download queue from Core Data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsoperationqueue

I want to download a certain amount of data from a server based on Core Data local database that contains links to the content.

I then want to have a table view that would dynamically display the content being downloaded one by one in a queue list.
It would resemble something you see in iTunes app on iPhone where you have a table of songs or podcasts being downloaded with a progress bar indicator.

I've checkout out many tutorials on NSOperationQueue like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) or [this one](http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/) and I've also decided not to use [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) because it is outdated.

How exactly does one wrap the NSOperationQueue of items being downloaded into a UITableview with URLs taken from a Core Data database including download progress activity indicators and deletion of the element from the Table View once its done downloading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my research on that topic I've ended up with writing my own custom class for the download queue.
`NSOperationQueue`, in my opinion, has several disadvantages connected with control of `NSOperations` - for example you can't move them up or down - only change their priorities from high to low.

I've also opted out using the  `ASIHTTPRequest framework` because, as I've said earlier, it is outdated.

I've based my class on `NSMutableArray` to hold queue elements and `NSMutableDictionary` to hold some values for them.

Comment: @dineshprasanna Please don't get me wrong, but this is a totally custom class and in no way it will help you or anyone else to achieve your goal. I suggest you start from scratch by having an `NSMutableArray` of HTTP requests that would do your thing. Hope this helps

Comment: ok sir,its not a problem.Actually i have implemented but i have one problem from that (i.e) when i am trying to reload the table all progressbar are started a blinking so its make a big problem for me,In this case what i have supposed to do could you help me.if possible means could you provide your mailid i will send the code through this.

Comment: @dineshprasanna I suggest you create a new question on StackOverflow. The problem shouldn't be too hard to solve :)